# React JS - How can I change fonts family on a specific page?

Tags: css, reactjs, font-family

In the react application I developed, I generally use the ubuntu font. I just want to use nunito font for login and register page. As an example, I showed my login page. I want to change all kinds of text styles such as form items, buttons, titles (h1) in this card, how can I do this?

```
 return (
<div className="centerItems login">
  <Button
    className="back-to-home"
    href="https://www.example.com/"
    type="default"
    icon={<HomeOutlined />}
    size={"medium"}
  />
  <Card className="login-card">
    <div className="centerItems">
      <Image preview={false} width={200} src={logo} />
      <h1 style={{ marginBottom: 8 }}>Login</h1>
    </div>
    <div className="login-form">
    <LoginForm className="centerItems" />
    </div>
  </Card>
</div>
);
```

Comment: modular scss can help or inline css

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans I am writing as sccs but is there an easy way without writing one by one because I have to write separately for button h1 or else I can't see any change or I am doing something wrong

Comment: Did you try using ID attribute as selector? or class attribute

Comment: What does this have to do with React? Use basic CSS for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve what you want.
I'm going to be assuming your loginpage component file is "LoginPage.js"
Since the methods for both loginpage and registerpages are the same I'm only going to show how to do it for the loginpage.

### By importing induvidual css files

1. In your LoginPage.js, add `import './LoginPage.css` ( Assuming the css file is in the same page as the LoginPage.js )
2. Add your styles there

#### Here is an example

In your LoginPage.js, return something like this -

```
import "./LoginPage.css"

export default function LoginPage() {
  return <div className="LoginPage-container"></div>
}
```

And in your LoginPage.css -

```
.LoginPage-container {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Nunito";
}

.LoginPage-container h1 {
  /*Styles for loginpage h1 here*/
}
```

### By giving your component a className

When you call your component in your main file, add a className to it like so -

```
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage.js"

return (
  <LoginPage className="LoginPage-container" /> 
);
```

Then style it in your main css file using the className "LoginPage-container" ( Like in the last example )

Answer (score 2):

No need to write any scripts.
You can do it with CSS alone. Since you have the `.login` class in the wrapper ensure that you also have the unique class name in the register form and then you can add the CSS like this,

```
.login * {
  font-family: <your-fontfamily>
}

.register * {
  font-family: <your-fontfamily>
}
```

[OR]

If you can able to add class in the  tag itself by using router logic based on which page you currently are then you can add the `font-family` to the `body` tag with the class name you added. like this

Consider that class name I added using router logic to body is `nunito-font`

```
body.nunito-font {
 font-family: <your-fontfamily>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to import css file how many fonts, you want to use. example [add multiple fonts](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-sunset-n1ltsq)

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Pangolin&family=Roboto&display=swap");
```

I chose three fonts. and you can add to apply html

```
 document.documentElement.style.fontFamily = "Pangolin";
```

if you want to apply body tag

```
 document.body.style.fontFamily = "Pangolin";
```

and at your root App component. make a fun to add based on the url here is my example

```
 useEffect(() => {
    addFontBasedOnRoute();
  }, [pathname]);

  const addFontBasedOnRoute = useCallback(() => {
    switch (pathname) {
      case "/":
        document.documentElement.style.fontFamily = data[0];
        break;
      case "/about":
        document.documentElement.style.fontFamily = data[1];
        break;
      case "/blog":
        document.documentElement.style.fontFamily = data[2];
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }, [pathname]);
```